# Do I have to make the possibilities of position of 4th minimum?

Tags: heap

A Min heap was constructed and the place of second minimum is at the right child of the root.
You are asked to mark all possible places of the fourth minimum, assuming that duplicates
don’t exists in the data structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no duplicates in a min heap, the parent of each node is less than the child.

Each node can have any value but must not be the same as another.
To make the diagram easier, just use integers.

```
            [1]
    [A]             [2]
[B]     [C]     [D]     [E]
```

- D and E are not ordered.
- D is greater than 2.
- E is greater than 2.
- A is greater than 1 but not 2.

So either A, B, C, D, or E could be 4.